# Winforms binding to null property

Tags: .net, winforms, entity-framework, poco, nullable

I am using EF/POCO objects and when binding textbox to nullable double some strange things happen. After I enter values and change focus to the next one the value in the box I just edited clears out. 
I bind my properties like this:

```
distanceTextEdit.DataBindings.Add("Text",
                                _routeControlVM.Route,
                                "Distance",
                                false,
                                DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged,
                                string.Empty);
```

What could cause this behavior ?

**EDIT:** Ok. Problem was in API of the DataBindings. I just changed false to true and everything works now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data must be formatted before it can be bound to nullable properties where I see that you are disabling it exclusively. Try with formatting enabled.

**EDIT**: I've just noticed you already enabled formatting with `DataBindings.Add(.., .., .., true, ..);`